# Hosting a WCF service inside a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am having some trouble hosting a WCF service inside a Windows Service.
I can start my WCF service in VS2008 and by navigating to the base address in my app.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCF.IndexerBehavior"
        name="WCF.Indexer">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCF.IIndexer">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WCFService/Action/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCF.IndexerBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I can see it works fine, I get the page saying I created a service and code samples on how to use it are shown.

Now my next step was to create a Windows Service to host my WCF shown above.

I just used te windows service template, it gave me a Program.cs and Service1.cs which I renamed to WindowsServiceHost.cs. In it I have:

```
private ServiceHost host;

        public WindowsServiceHost()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var serviceType = typeof(Indexer.WCF.Indexer);
                host = new ServiceHost(serviceType);
                host.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (host != null)
            {
                host.Close();
            }
        }
```

Everything compiles fine, I can run InstallUtil (I defined an installer).
The service used to start and stop immediately but disabling Windows Defender got rid of this.
Now the service starts (As a network service) and stays up (I think), but when I navigate to the base address, I get the not found page.
Another weird thing is when I try to stop the service (which is still displayed as running) I get:

Error 1061: The service cannot accept control messages at this time

I've tried everything but am at a loss.

Comment: Does your service run as a standalone executable that can be run from the command line, i.e. as a self-hosting application? You'll need to get this to work before you can run it as a Windows service in the way you describe. 

To debug this kind of problem it can be useful to introduce a time delay in the OnStart so you can attach the Visual Studio debugger to the service process before the rest of the code executes. It can also help to log exceptions to the Windows event log rather than swallowing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure what the reason really is - just to confirm, we self-host WCF services in Windows services all the time and it generally works perfectly fine.

Two points you could try - just to get a feeling for the behavior and a potential clue for the problem:

1) I notice you open the ServiceHost with just the type of the service - that works, but you might still want to add a base address even to the call of the `new ServiceHost()` - like this:

```
host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, 
                       new Uri("http://localhost:8181/WCFService/Action/");
```

Can you navigate to that address and get the service page??

2) The other thing I noticed is that your service seems to be called `Indexer.WCF.Indexer` as specified in the typeof() before opening the host, but in the config file, the `name=` on the `<service>` tag is only "WCF.Indexer".

Could you possibly try to change that tag to read:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WCF.IndexerBehavior"
         name="Indexer.WCF.Indexer">
```

Does that help? Are you now able to see the service page when navigating to it in the browser?

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Self-hosting HTTP in a Windows service may require registering the endpoint with HttpCfg.exe.  Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the catch statement, there may be an error that you are not seeing